# Can I replace a redirect status with any apache standard modules?

Tags: redirect, httpd.conf, apache-2.2

Our environment are apache2.2 + mod_perl2 + perl app

the perl app output 302 Found
but from SEO reason
I wanna change the status to 301 Moved Permanently 
only from Google bot

and If it need to edit application
we have to request other software firm.
so I wanna resolve with httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

Well, i'd use mod_alias with Redirect or RedirectMatch directive, for a basic 301 redirection, something like this works :

```
Redirect permanent /redirect http://www.example.com
```

For more elaborated setups => [mod_alias documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)